# Почему родительские html-элементы добавляют дополнительное пространство по высоте??? И как это отключить?

Tags: html, css

```css
button {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
}

svg {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    fill: #000;
}

div {
    width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<button><p>some text</p></button>
<button>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512"  xml:space="preserve">
        <g>
            <rect y="16" width="512" height="96"/>
            <rect y="208" width="512" height="96"/>
            <rect y="400" width="512" height="96"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
</button>
<div>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512"  xml:space="preserve">
        <g>
            <rect y="16" width="512" height="96"/>
            <rect y="208" width="512" height="96"/>
            <rect y="400" width="512" height="96"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
<div>
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="image">
</div>
```

Получилось примерно такое

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что я получаю в `<button><p>some text</p></button>` согласно стилевому блоку если его можно так назвать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для `<p>` элемента я прописал 16px высоты, по идее родительский элемент должен был принять высоту и ширину дочернего, но вместо указанных `16px` высоты я имею в родительском `button-е` - `18.4px`.

Далее та же закономерность для вложенных `svg-векторов` и вложенных картинок.

Вот что показыват стилевой блок для

```
<button>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512"  xml:space="preserve">
        <g>
            <rect y="16" width="512" height="96"/>
            <rect y="208" width="512" height="96"/>
            <rect y="400" width="512" height="96"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
</button>
```

:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И то же самое для svg-вектора в div-е и вложенной картинки:

Для кода

```
<div>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512"  xml:space="preserve">
        <g>
            <rect y="16" width="512" height="96"/>
            <rect y="208" width="512" height="96"/>
            <rect y="400" width="512" height="96"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для кода

```
<div>
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="image">
</div>
```

Результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно `svg` имеет ширину `40px` и высоту `40px`. А родительский `div` уже имеет ширину `40px` и высоту `44px`. Откуда взялись эти дополнительные 4 пикселя?
Как убрать дополнительные пиксели которые создаются вложенностью элементов???

P.S. Вот стилевой блок для SVG:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот для непосредственно картинки (картинка сама по себе черного цвета размерами 20х20 px)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1) `border` на `<button>`; 2) `line-height` на `<p>`; 3) `vertical-align` на `<svg>` и `<img>`